# share point document version still incrementing even after disabling the versioning and minor versioning

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, versioning, console-application

I have a SP 2013 document library with content approval and versioning enabled. Now through a console application I am disabling the content approval and versioning to updated the document and after the document gets updated, again enabling the content approval and versioning for the library. Now if I see the document the version has been incremented.

So, how could I update the document without changing the version of the document 
 programattically.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SPListItem.SystemUpdate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms481195%28v%3Doffice.15%29) to update a ListItem while not modifying the author or editor. If you pass `false` no new version will be created.

Do not change the approval- or version-settings on the list. Leave them as is.

Comment: thanks, @Gaurravs I was in a bit of a hurry. I re-phrased the answer.

Comment: okay. Removed comment

Comment: I have this already in my code. But still I can see the version is incremented.
For example. I created one draft version 0.1 with doc name as abc.docx. Now when I run my console , I can see the code has updated the doc file as well as the version is upgraded to 1.0 and the Status of the document is Approved.

Comment: Are you still disable versions/approval? I can see the same behaviour when I disable versions, update, then re-enable versions. Do not do that. Simply call `item.SystemUpdate(false)`